# get a value of a key associated with other key's values in dictionaries Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries and json list and I need to grab a value of a specific key based on the value of a key from another dictionary. My data looks like this:

```
opps = [{'Product2Id': '100','Price': '1645'}, {'Product2Id': '101','Price': '5478'}]
products = [{'Id': '100', 'Name': 'Insertion'}, [{'Id': '101', 'Name': 'Print'}]
sales_json = {'Insertion': {'name': 'BAZ', 'id': '95'}, 'Print': {'name': 'BIC', 'id': '105'}
```

I need to loop through opps and assign a value to a new variable from `sales_json`. But for a specific Id that are stored in `products` and in `opps`

I tried the following:

```
for index, my_dict in enumerate(opps):
    new_name = sales_json[products[my_dict["Product2Id"]]["Name"]]["name"]
```

Gives me an error. 
The desired output is:

```
print(new_name)
BAZ,
BIC
```

Comment: Verify the structure of your data. You are missing closing braces in some areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the list **products** as a dictionary. Instead, you should first build a product number to name dictionary from it:

```
prod_num_to_name = {d['Id']: d['Name'] for d in products}
```

Then, you can run the loop you wanted, modified like this:

```
for index, my_dict in enumerate(opps):
    new_name = sales_json[prod_num_to_name[my_dict["Product2Id"]]]["name"]
    print new_name
```

Answer (score 0):

To return a `list` of names that match the criteria, using a List Comprehension:

```
names = [ sales_json[product['Name']]['name'] for opp in opps for product in products if product['Id'] == opp['Product2Id']]
print (names)
```

Prints the list of names:

```
['BAZ', 'BIC']
```